# mongoose: filtering $lookup in aggregation

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following aggregation code in mongoose, it runs fine, but I'm looking to filter the result:

```
Mov.aggregate(
       [
              { $sort: { _id: 1, car_id: 1, area: 1 } },
         {
           $group:
             {
               _id: "$car_id",
               lastLocation: { $last: "$area" }
             }
         },
                     {
            $lookup: {
                from: Car.collection.name,
                "localField": "_id",
                "foreignField": "_id",
                as: 'cars'
            }
        },    
      ]
         )
        .then(movs => {
            res.send(movs);
        }).catch(err => {
            res.status(500).send({
                message: err.message
            });
 });
```

How can I filter the `Car.collection.name` in `$lookup` where I want to get only cars with `{"active":true}` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a different lookup strategy. Following is the updated query:

```
Mov.aggregate([{
    $sort: {
      "_id": 1,
      "car_id": 1,
      "area": 1
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$car_id",
      lastLocation: {
        $last: "$area"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: Car.collection.name,
      let: {
        "_id": "$_id"
      },
      pipeline: [{
        $match: {
          $expr: {
            $eq: ["$_id", "$$_id"]
          },
          active: true
        }
      }],
      "as": "cars"
    }
  }
]).then(movs => {
  res.send(movs);
}).catch(err => {
  res.status(500).send({
    message: err.message
  });
});
```

You can check the following link for more information on this lookup strategy https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/

Comment: I get {"message":"arguments to $lookup must be strings, let: { _id: \"$_id\" } is type object"}

Comment: @Hisham which mongo version are you using?

Comment: v3.4.7, I think I have to upgrade to v3.6 if there is no solution for the lookup syntax in my mongodb current version

Comment: Yes, you should upgrade to not even v3.6 but v4.0 to get some more cool features :)